# Visual Studio couldn't find stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, ado.net

I added stored procedure in SQL Server - code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insertinfo]
    @model NVARCHAR(255),
    @price INT,
    @id INT
AS
    INSERT INTO computers (model, price, id)
    VALUES (@model, @price, @id)

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getinfo]
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM computers
GO
```

After that I tried to use it from Visual Studio

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionSTring))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlExpression,con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter modelparam = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@model",
                    Value = model
                };

    SqlParameter priceparam = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@price",
                    Value = price
                };

    SqlParameter idparam = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@id",
                    Value = id
                };

    cmd.Parameters.Add(modelparam);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(priceparam);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(idparam);

    int rid = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and I get the following error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'sp_insertinfo'.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: One possible issue could be that the connection string is not pointing to the right database. Another possible issue could be that you haven't created the procedure on the database you are using for the application. With the information you have provided one can only assume. Also, please read [this link](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-naming-stored-procedures/) and avoid naming your stored procedures sp_.

Comment: looks like it was a issue of procedure name i change names to insert_info and get_info , now it works just fine . thx

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

I changed procedure names from sp_insertinfo to insert_info and sp_getinfo -> get_info and it works fine

Comment: The `sp_` procedure name prefix is used for system procs and should be avoided for user procs per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql).

Comment: For further reading here is an excellent post on the sp_ prefix. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix